# Problems with Printing JSON Data in One Line

Tags: php, json

I have JSON Data i need to print categories in one line, but categories have multi values.

I try to export tags but i stuck on printing values in one line.

Example from `"categories"` Print text: **Categories1, Categories2, Categories3, Categories4**

I try bellow but not working:

```
foreach ($jf['data']['feed'] as $item1) {

    $item = $item1['article'];

 foreach($item['categories'] as $categories1) {
    echo $categories123;
 }
```

JSON File

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "feed": [
      {
        "article": {
          "id": "165354",
          "title": "Title1",
          "image_url": "example.com/image1.png",
          "native_app_url": "example.com/article1",
          "article_url": "example.com/article1",
          "article_type": "Article",
          "created_at": "2020-01-15T16:55:01Z",
          "featured_time": "2020-02-19T17:19:33Z",
          "author_name": "2",
          "matches": [

          ],
          "categories": [
            "Categories1",
            "Categories2",
            "Categories3",
            "Categories4"
          ],
          "tags": [
            "Tags1",
            "Tags2",
            "Tags3"
          ],
          "embed_code": "<embed>12453</embed>",
          "synd_code": "<embed>121245</embed>"
        }
      },
      {
        "article": {
          "id": "112354",
          "title": "Title2",
          "image_url": "example.com/image2.png",
          "native_app_url": "example.com/article2",
          "article_url": "example.com/article2",
          "article_type": "Article",
          "created_at": "2020-01-11T16:55:01Z",
          "featured_time": "2020-01-19T17:19:33Z",
          "author_name": "1",
          "matches": [

          ],
          "categories": [
            "Categories1",
            "Categories2",
            "Categories3",
            "Categories4"
          ],
          "tags": [
            "Tags1",
            "Tags2",
            "Tags3"
          ],
          "embed_code": "<embed>123</embed>",
          "synd_code": "<embed>12345</embed>"
        }
      },
      {
        "article": {
        ...
        }
      }
    ],
    "next_page": 2
  },
  "message": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `implode` to insert a delimiter between array elements.

```
$categories = implode(", ", $item['categories']);
```

If you only want a limited number, slice the array before imploding.

```
$category_limit = 4; // only show first 4 categories
$categories = implode(", ", array_slice($item['categories'], 0, $category_limit));
```

Comment: Hi again i have one more question from my JSON Script i add new function links from JSON Feed "article_url" to my RSS Feed as <link> tag. I add fuction `if (isset($item['article_url'])) $newItem->addChild('link', $item['article_url']);` but get output <link/> i check JSON Feed and i see that have link in key "article_url" @Barmar

Comment: It would be better to use `if (!empty($item['article_url']))`. This will skip empty strings.